# Shopify Debut Theme, Change Quantity To 10 If Less Than 9

Tags: shopify, liquid, cart

I’m new to Shopify. Hoping I post this in the right place. I’m trying to add an if then statement to my order quantity in the Debut theme. I have minimum order quantity setup so it starts at a value of 10 in the cart, but I want to change it so that if customers enter less than 10, it will automatically change back to 10. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried a couple things and didn’t get very far since I have not programmed a website before. Thanks in advance for your time and help. Here is a screenshot of what I have tried. Thanks again! I really appreciate these forums and being able to ask so many experts for help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EgIxI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You just need a simple input field

```
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" value="10" pattern="[1-9]{1,}0" class="... whatever you have in the image ..." />
```

Instead of step, I have used `pattern` to match multiples of 10. I'm using `type="text"` since `pattern` doesn't work for `type="number"` and to show numeric keypad to mobile/touchscreen users I'm using `inputmode="numeric"`